# Pasar un Array de objetos por Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estoy tratando de pasar un Array de Objetos desde JavaScript a PHP mediante Ajax, pero no me funciona, este es mi codigo:

```
function actualizarRoles() {
    var arr = [];
    $("#panelroles input[type=\"checkbox\"]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            arr.push({id: $(this).attr('id'), permitido: true});
        } else {
            arr.push({id: $(this).attr('id'), permitido: false});
        }
    });
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(arr);
    $.ajax({
        url: "./model/usuario.php?dato=actualizarroles",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data : jsonString},
        success:
                function (r) {
                    ocultarModalRolesUsuario();
                    mensajeOK(r);
                }
    });
}
```

Luego para recibirlo en PHP intento esto:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        echo $d;
    }
```

Pero obtengo el error al recibirlo:

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string on line 03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres tratar a tu objeto como un Array, debes codificarlo y de nuevo decodificarlo.

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($_POST['data']), True);
```

Si quieres tratarolo como un objeto debes meterlo en un foreach y hacer referencia a la key que quieras obtener con ->

```
 $data= $_POST['data']);
 foreach ($data as $value){
    echo $value->id;
 }
```